# Upgrade Apache 2 to 2.2.22 on Debian 6.0

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, lamp

How I can upgrade Apache 2 from 2.2.17 to 2.2.22 on Debian 6.0 (x86)?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Unless 2.2.22 has some new feature you absolutely cannot live without, I recommend you stick with the version the debian apache team deems "stable for a production environment". If you're worried about some kind of security bug in 2.2.17, rest assured that the debian team will have applied a fix, almost certainly well before you first learned about it.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you should only do this when you really need it for something, as it is very easy to mess up your system with this method.

If you still want to do it though, I recommend using the `Testing` repository, rather than the `sid` repository, as this repository is usually a little more stable. 
The way to do this is exactly the same as in hangover's answer, only replace `sid` with `testing`. Both repositories have Apache 2.2.22.

Again, you should not do this unless you really need it. I have made that mistake before. 
And do **not** forget to remove the `testing` repository afterwards, or set up [apt pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).

As a sidenote, if you want the rest of your webserver up-to-date, I can recommend the [dotdeb repository](http://www.dotdeb.org) for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Apache v2.2.22 in `squeeze-backports`, so you can install it from debian [`sid` repo](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=sid&arch=i386&keywords=apache2) **at your own extreme risk** - package from sid repo can create lot of troubles with unresolvable dependencies.

Add sid repo to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

Run

```
apt-get update && apt-get -t sid install apache2
```

After installation of apache comment line with sid repo in your `sources.list` and run `apt-get update` again.

**NOTE**: Doing this is *highly* contraindicated, and any and all subsequent problems with your system are completely your own. It's also very hard to reverse.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you can do a dist-upgrade to wheezy, which should upgrade your version to 2.2.22.

I'm having the same issue right now, and since these are production boxes I'm nervous about the downtime of doing a full upgrade, so I'm thinking of using Shadur's sid repo solution; of course, I'll be testing in my dev environment first to ensure there are no issues with it.

Additionally, in response to the comments about *why* someone would want to do this upgrade, there are security vulnerabilities in versions 1.3.x, 2.0.x-2.0.64, and 2.2.x:

http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/apache-httpd-remote-denia/